# Python create clickable TUI entries

Tags: python

I have a TUI for my scripts but sometimes the computer is only used with a mouse, so I want to make them clickable entries for the user

the code uses python

The code is too long to paste here so here's a [link to the github page](https://github.com/ppigmans/tbui/blob/master/TBUIR)

Basicly what I want is clickable terminal text that opens one of the programs inside the code to minimalize the load on the computer, in this case the code runs on a raspberry pi, and because of the limited RAM and the 8 GB SD card I try to keep everything as minimalistic as possible.

so I was looking around the web while I posted this answer and found TKinter for graphical light weight gui's, I started messing around and found that in order to have my scripts show with text an all I needed a terminal window inside the gui, so I googled a bit and found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273573/write-to-terminal-in-tkinter-gui/299790#299790)

someone was basicly doing the same as I had in mind but he faced an error, surprisingly after a good 1 hour of trying to solve it, I actually did and now have a working GUI with buttons and terminal unit :)

----------------------------FINALLY FULL EXPLAINATION-------------------------

So, After finding out a TUI in xterm is impossible to click at I looked into different options, I found multiple option, one was using zenity but I didn't like it because I installed it before ( keep in mind this is a raspberry pi with limited 1 GB ram) and it nearly drained the RPI from its memory, practicly terrified this was going to happen again I skipped zenity.

I saw Tkinter, which is basicly text to GUI its simplistic, light (since its nearly all code instead of heavy GUI like zenity) and just easy to use if you know Python, so I looked further into it and saw nearly endless possibilities.

Thus I started rewriting my TUI to a light GUI (eventually it became its own Thin client as seen on [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FChu.png))

However when I started I was unable to get it working like I wanted (since most my own tools rely on a terminal based execution (user ease of use :) ), so after what, a couple of hours of googling I found this [unixSE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273573/write-to-terminal-in-tkinter-gui/299790#299790), that code was EXACTLY what I needed, but as I saw it was bugged, so I looked into it (its a hobby and my job to fix stuff from others!), some minutes later I fixed it up and got it in working order, so I started editing most of it, eventually using snippets of it in my own code.

Nearly two weeks later (WOOPS!) it is finally done, the code is uploaded on [github](https://github.com/ppigmans/Tool-box/blob/master/bin/TBMenu) for anyone wanting to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Downloaded and installed Tkinter and after a bit of tinkering I made it work

**--------------------------------ADDED EXPLAINATION----------------------------------**

so I was looking around the web while I posted this answer and found TKinter for graphical light weight gui's, I started messing around and found that in order to have my scripts show with text an all I needed a terminal window inside the gui, so I googled a bit and found 
[this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273573/write-to-terminal-in-tkinter-gui/299790#299790)

someone was basicly doing the same as I had in mind but he faced an error, surprisingly after a good 1 hour of trying to solve it, I actually did and now have a working GUI with buttons and terminal unit :)

----------------------------FINALLY FULL EXPLAINATION-------------------------

So, After finding out a TUI in xterm is impossible to click at I looked into different options, I found multiple option, one was using zenity but I didn't like it because I installed it before ( keep in mind this is a raspberry pi with limited 1 GB ram) and it nearly drained the RPI from its memory, practicly terrified this was going to happen again I skipped zenity.

I saw Tkinter, which is basicly text to GUI its simplistic, light (since its nearly all code instead of heavy GUI like zenity) and just easy to use if you know Python, so I looked further into it and saw nearly endless possibilities.

Thus I started rewriting my TUI to a light GUI (eventually it became its own Thin client as seen on [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FChu.png))

However when I started I was unable to get it working like I wanted (since most my own tools rely on a terminal based execution (user ease of use :) ), so after what, a couple of hours of googling I found this [unixSE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273573/write-to-terminal-in-tkinter-gui/299790#299790), that code was EXACTLY what I needed, but as I saw it was bugged, so I looked into it (its a hobby and my job to fix stuff from others!), some minutes later I fixed it up and got it in working order, so I started editing most of it, eventually using snippets of it in my own code.

Nearly two weeks later (WOOPS!) it is finally done, the code is uploaded on [github](https://github.com/ppigmans/Tool-box/blob/master/bin/TBMenu) for anyone wanting to see it.

**---------------------------- ZANNA'S WISH! ----------------------------**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#title           : TBMenu
#Omschijving     : Geeft een simpel menu weer dat interactief is/shows a menu which is interactive
#Made by         : Patrick Pigmans
#Made for        : Servicenet-ITF
#Made at         : 2nd of August 2016
#python_version  : 2.7.12/3.5.2
#=======================================================================#

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os
from os import system as cmd

def test():
    os.system('sudo xterm -into %d -geometry 100x28 -sb -e overscan &' % terminfo)

def sysinfo():
    os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 100x28 -sb -e systeminfo &' % terminfo)

def ipconf():
    os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 51x11 -sb -e ipconfig &' % terminfo)

def Uninstall():
    os.system('sudo xterm -into %d -geometry 100x28 -sb -e TBuninstall &' % terminfo)

WINDOW_SIZE = "1024x768"
top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

Button1  = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Systeem informatie opvragen", command=sysinfo)
Button1.pack()

Button2  = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="IP adres achterhalen", command = ipconf)
Button2.pack()

Button3  = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Zwarte balken weghalen", command = test)
Button3.pack()

Button4 = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Tools Verwijderen", command = Uninstall)
Button4.pack()

termin = Frame(top, height=1000, width=1000)

termin.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
terminfo = termin.winfo_id()


def send_entry_to_terminal(*args):
    cmd("%s" % (BasicCovTests))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    top.title('KEUZE MENU')
    top.mainloop()
```

The code normally goes with the rest of my tools since its just a menu :P

Comment: This answer could use some elaboration to be more useful to others

Comment: added elaboration :)

Comment: haha you did add elaboration but not the essential bits, except as a link... this link will die if the other question is deleted, so I think you should include the actual set up here :)

Comment: Will do! and what else should I add while im at it?

Comment: If I want to do the same thing as you, I should be able to do it using only your answer here as a guide.

Comment: Why not use a simple launcher (`.desktop` file) running the terminal with your command?

Comment: @Zanna I will once I have time today :P

Comment: @JacobVlijm I did but customers didn't like it, so now I made a simplistic GUI

Comment: @Zanna take a look :)

Comment: please put the full explanation in your answer, not question :)

Comment: @Zanna done :) sorry im at work so I don't get to post every time

Comment: Haha but it's a story and some links. I would rather the code were here!

Comment: You sure about that @Zanna xD its quite some code

Comment: @Zanna Its there now :) most of the comments and some of the code is dutch soo... yeah

Comment: upvoted! ^_^ cool question & well done for making that

Comment: @Zanna and to think im just a simple IT service guy XD but thanks for the Upvote!